# Checking user verification using '==' on a Bool throws error using Swift and Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, verification

Im trying to check if there is a user and if they have verified their account (by phone number) and if there is and they have then let them continue but if there is a user that has not verified their phone number segue them to verify their phone number. My problem is that i set "phoneNumberVerified" in the Parse User class as a Bool but then I try to check using an if statement I get the error: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnyObject!' and 'Bool'

Code to check user and verification status:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

    if currentUser == nil || currentUser!["phoneNumberVerified"] == nil {

        performSegueWithIdentifier("showInitialView", sender: self)

    } else {

        if let numberIsVerified = currentUser!["phoneNumberVerified"] as? Bool {

            if currentUser != nil && numberIsVerified == false {
                performSegueWithIdentifier("showVerifyUserView", sender: self)

            } else if currentUser != nil && numberIsVerified == true {
                performSegueWithIdentifier("showMyPostsView", sender: self)

            } else {
                performSegueWithIdentifier("showInitialView", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you post the error log? it will be more helpful.

Comment: So, what is the error message saying?  How do you think you could fix it?  How do you downcast in Swift?

Comment: The build fails if I run the app because of the Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnyObject!' and 'Bool' error

Comment: I know that is what it is saying, what I meant is for you to think about what it might mean. Have you read the chapter in the Swift book on type casting and specifically down casting

Comment: I fixed it. I haven, I definitely will though! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just try and downcast it as a Bool

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {

        if let numberIsVerified = currentUser["phoneNumberVerified"] as? Bool {

            if numberIsVerified == false {
                performSegueWithIdentifier("showVerifyUserView", sender: self)

            } else if numberIsVerified == true {
                performSegueWithIdentifier("showMyPostsView", sender: self)

            } else {
                performSegueWithIdentifier("showInitialView", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest adding a check for `currentUser == nil` before the `if let`.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it! But revealed another issue. When the user launches the app for the first time the value for "phoneNumberVerified" is undefined. It crashed because its nil. Is there a way to set it as false when the app is launched but not override if it if a user that has verified their number opens the app? Sorry I didn't see your comment but yeah thats is the issue now

Comment: If it is nil then that means the user haste signed up so then I would simply segue them to the sign up view?

Comment: i don't understand your questin @midgyb

Comment: @midgyb Yes, you would call `performSegueWithIdentifier("showInitialView", sender: self)`

Comment: Alright, thank you so much for your help! However, now no segues are being preformed. Any ideas why?

Comment: Dude the only variables in your code are `currentUser` and `numberIsVerified`. Check those @midgyb

Comment: I have, Im only asking because I have checked and everything checks out

Comment: @migdyb check that you named all your segues in storyboard

Comment: Thats what I thought but they all check out

Comment: @midgyb print all your variables. Either one of your variables is failing, or your segue setup on storyboard is flawed.

Comment: I always forget I can bring out a variable to check it. I get nil for currentUser and nothing in printed for numberIsVerified

Answer (score 1):

@Paulw11 is giving you a good hint.

You'll need to compare equatable types in Swift, so if you'e storing a Boolean as part of your current parse user you'll need to cast it as such.

You can even do it in parenthesis, in place:

```
(currentUser!["phoneNumberVerified"] as! Bool)
```

I don't recall exactly how Parse stores bools and if the types are directly compatible but that should get you on the right track. The key is the types need to be the same (or inherit from the same places in some cases) to be equitable.